# run a function for every result that is checked

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How would i go about running a function for every result that is checked within a dynamic selection of choices. Currently https://jsfiddle.net/7sx1jyg3/3 has the code for my table with a few random filler "results"

The information i need to grab when i click generate, is the value of the checkbox for each instance that is selected. Currently with the code i have the value of each checkbox is the ID of the instance within the database which is the information i need in order to generate the PDF correctly. The most relevant code to this question within the jsfiddle are the following lines:

Every selected item gets added to the queuedValues observable array and the generate function is the function to be run when i click the generate button so that function is where i would complete the url information so checkedValue would be set to the id of each selected result

```
self.queuedValues = ko.observableArray([]);
self.generate = function() {
    window.open("{{ url_for('genreport') }}/" + qvm.letter() + '/' + checkedValue);
  }
```

Comment: Is your question how to handle the URL?

Comment: no, my question is how to get the information from the table to redirect to the URL the ID of the result is already supplied by the query, i just need to grab the id of the results i select.

Comment: What does your user select at the screen? What does the report which is generated by your app look like? Why do you `need to convert this to multi-selection` and by the word `this`, what do you mean? Your question is unclear so I don't think some one could help you. Please edit your question and clear out your problem. Also a jsfiddle will help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of [using the `checked` binding with an array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html#example-adding-checkboxes-bound-to-an-array).

To have an array that contains the `id`s of selected rows, create the array in the parent object, not in each row. In the checkbox, bind `checked` to the array (using `$parent` because you're in a `foreach` scope). Bind `value` to `id`.

When you check a box, the `id` will be added to the array; when you uncheck a box, the `id` will be removed from the array.

```js
vm = {
  rows: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'First'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Second'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Third'
  }],
  selectedIds: ko.observableArray([])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedIds, value: id">
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(selectedIds())"></div>
```

Comment: That did exactly what I needed it to, just need to figure out the generation part now thank you very much